# Closed Type Families based Data Types a la Carte didn't work for generalized types

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

As we know, in order to solve the EP, we can use [Data types a la carte](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-functional-programming/article/data-types-a-la-carte/14416CB20C4637164EA9F77097909409) to extend both constructors and behaviors of our program. The paper adopts a typeclass implemented automated injection to ease the writing of our program.

However, the solution has limitations since we can't do backtracking: for relation `f :<: g`, `f` has to be atomic and `g` must be constructed in a linked-list shape:

```hs
type Arith = Val :+: Add

type NonAtomic = Arith :<: (Val :+: (Add :+: Mult))

-- op1 :: Arith :<: f => Fix f -> Fix f
-- op1 f = f `add0` val0 2

type NonListLike = Val :<: ((Mult :+: Val) :+: Add)

-- op2 :: Fix ((Val :+: Mult) :+: Add)
-- op2 = val0 2

type Associativity = (Add :+: (Mult :+: Val)) :<: ((Add :+: Mult) :+: Val)

-- op3 :: Fix ((Add :+: Mult) :+: Val)
-- op3 = val0 2 <+> val0 3
```

This may cause problems if we want to add some type aliases. Also, it will not help to catch if some types appear more than once on the right-hand side.

According to [Bahr's paper](https://bahr.io/pubs/files/bahr14wgp-paper.pdf), we can add backtracking to solve the above problems using closed type families. Instead of typeclass, we can use type-level functions to search the existence of f in g for relation `f :<: g`.

```hs
data Pos = Here | L Pos | R Pos | Sum Pos Pos

data Res = Found Pos | NotFound | Ambiguous

-- | search the existence of f in g
type family Elem (f :: Type -> Type) (g :: Type -> Type) :: Res

-- | search all branches in g. reject if f appears more than once in g
type family Choose (f :: Type -> Type) (g :: Type -> Type) (a :: Res) (b :: Res) :: Res 

-- | search all parts of f if f is a compound expression.
type family Sum' (a :: Res) (b :: Res) :: Res

-- | relation `f :<: g`
class Subsume (res :: Res) f g
```

I did a experiment and it did work for concrete types:

```hs
type Arith = Val :+: Add

op1Fixed :: (Subsume (Elem Arith f) Arith f, f ~ (Val :+: (Add :+: Mult)))
    => Fix f
    -> Fix f
op1Fixed f = f <+> val 2
```

but things went wrong when f generalized:

```hs
op1Fixed :: (Subsume (Elem Arith f) Arith f)
    => Fix f
    -> Fix f
op1Fixed f = f <+> val 2

-- Could not deduce (Subsume (Elem Add f) Add f)
--  arising from a use of ‘<+>’
-- Could not deduce (Subsume (Elem Val f) Val f)
--  arising from a use of ‘val’
```

even if I explicitly show that we can find corresponding constructors from f:

```hs
op1Fixed :: forall f a b. (Subsume ('Found ('Sum a b)) Arith f)
    => Fix f
    -> Fix f
op1Fixed f = f <+> val 2

-- Could not deduce (Subsume (Elem Add f) Add f)
--  arising from a use of ‘<+>’
-- Could not deduce (Subsume (Elem Val f) Val f)
--  arising from a use of ‘val’
```

This renders the solution useless because of [open world assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-world_assumption). The program loses its flexibility to extend if `f` has to be known every time we want to add constructors.

Full source [here](https://pastebin.com/stVRRW5X)

Is there anything I miss?

Comment: Please try to make the question more self-contained, with enough information to reproduce the problem but also not so much code to dig through as in the pastebin. You know, [MCVE]...

Comment: Edited to reduce lengthy code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known limitation of the technique as they say in their discussion:

> ***Ground Signatures*** The most important limitation is that :≺: only
> works for ground types, i.e. neither side may contain variables.